# Amazon live app testing purchases: Can testers use a build downloaded from Amazon Underground to test purchases?

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, testing, amazon-in-app-purchase

I'm confused about how to test purchases in amazon Live App Testing before app is submitted and goes live. I set up a test in Live App Testing and submitted it. The build works fine locally in sandbox mode, if app is installed manually and App Tester is installed on the device as well. But when another tester downloads the app from the link that is automatically sent by Live App Testing service, the purchase service doesn't use sandbox mode and purchases fail. Does it mean that testers cannot use a build downloaded from Amazon Underground to test purchases and have to install the build manually instead?

Answer (score 2):

Okay, I think I found the issue. The live test app was submitted, but IAP items were not submitted. After they were submitted, they become available in the app, though this did not happen immediately. When I checked the app right after submitting the items, they were unavailable, but the next day they worked.
To summarize: to test purchases on live environment (not in sandbox mode), you need to submit the test app on the live app test dashboard and to submit each item on the In-App Items tab.

Comment: I have same issue, but IAP items is submitted(status is "Live")

Comment: @LawfulChaotic , I am facing the issue in Live app testing, my IAP item is already submitted. When i am making purchase then app shows this message "An error occurred while processing your purchase". Please help me if you can.